# SQLite TEXT comparison not working with database attached

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I have 2 `SQLITE` databases. Both schemas are the same.

There is a record table as following :

```
CREATE TABLE record_table
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,hash_key TEXT )
```

And I open one of them(as main ) and attached another one as A and execute the following `SQL`.

```
select  hash_key from record_table where _id not in 
(select _id from A.record_table)
```

the result:

> hash_key
>      3B12DA00C3394ADB9FB009508B5CE60B_201802208556

```
1 row returned
```

And I execute the following SQL to check is the hash_key( previous result) is in a database:

```
select hash_key from A.record_table where hash_key in 
(select  hash_key from record_table where _id not in 
(select _id from A.record_table))
```

The result is :

```
0 rows returned
```

Therefore I think the record_table in A database does not contain the hash_key = '3B12DA00C3394ADB9FB009508B5CE60B_201802208556' record but main database does .

So I think I can use the hash_key to find the same result as first SQL with the following SQL;

```
select hash_key from record_table where hash_key not in 
(select hash_key from A.record_table)
```

But there still no rows returned:

```
0 rows returned in 13ms from: select _id,hash_key from record_table 
where hash_key not in
(select hash_key from A.record_table)
```

Could anyone tell me what I am wrong ?

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the relation between id and hash_key? Do you always have the same id for a given hash_key, no matter which table?

Comment: No, the id with hash_key in the different database may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you MikeT!

I found when

```
 select _id,hash_key from record_table where hash_key not in 
 (select hash_key from A.record_table )
```

result:

```
return 0 rows
```

If I add **where hash_key is not null**

```
select _id,hash_key from record_table where hash_key not in 
(select hash_key from A.record_table where hash_key is not null )
```

result:

```
"8556"  "3B12DA00C3394ADB9FB009508B5CE60B_201802208556"
```

Therefore If I use SQL **' where xxx in ( ... )'** and  ( ... ) have null value the result may not same as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may let you see better how your SQL works.

- tables are in same DB (*for simplification*)

The equivalent to the main table is **record_table_a** as per :-

[image]

The equivalent of the attached DB is record_table_b as per :-

[image]

#### The 1st query

```
select  _id AS a_id, hash_key from record_table_a where _id not in 
    (select _id from record_table_b)
```

results in :-

[image]

i.e.because id **4** is not in table_b the hash key that is returned is the hash key from table_a (I've shown id as well, which is also from table a). The has key **6B12DA00C3394ADB9FB009508B5CE60B_201802208556** does in this case appears in table_b as id 3.

#### The 2nd query

```
select _id AS b_id, hash_key from record_table_b where hash_key in 
    (select  hash_key from record_table_a where _id not in 
        (select _id from record_table_b))
```

In this scenerio it returns id 3 for table_b and the hash_key **6B12DA00C3394ADB9FB009508B5CE60B_201802208556** from table_b as in this case it does exist as per :-

[image]

#### The 3rd query

```
select _id AS a_id, hash_key from record_table_a where hash_key not in 
   (select hash_key from record_table_b)
```

In this scenario it returns id 3 and hash key **5B12DA00C3394ADB9FB009508B5CE60B_201802208556** from table_a because the hash_key in table_a doesn't_exist in table_b as per :-

[image]